# Strapi V4 filter where relation does not exist

Tags: node.js, strapi

I'm setting up a comments-like system where comments have a `parent` field which relations to another comment. I want to be able to query the top level comment by finding comments that have no `parent` set, but I cannot see in the documentation any way to do this.

I tried this, but it doesn't look like the `$null` filter works on joins.

```js
            const posts = await strapi.entityService.findMany('api::post.post', {
                filters: {
                    thread: {
                        id: {
                            $eq: entity[0].id,
                        }
                    },
                    parent: {
                        $null: true,
                    }
                }
            });
```

And I get the error: **Only $and, $or and $not can by used as root level operators. Found $null.**

I can't find anything about this in the Strapi documentation but it seems like a pretty standard thing to do want to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I found a solution to this using the Strapi query API rather than the entity service:

```js
            const posts = await strapi.db.query('api::post.post').findMany({
                where: {
                    thread: entity[0].id,
                    parent: null
                }
            });
```

Comment: Is there any way for strapi v3?

Answer (score 8):

```
filters[relation_name][id][$null]=true
or
filters:{
  relation_name:{
    id:{
      $null:true
    }
  }
}
```

This helped me to filter out the record where a relation is null/doesn't exist.

Comment: this solution works with the REST api

Comment: Here's a link to the GitHub issue, one of the top comments describes a similar workaround: https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/12225

Answer (score 0):

This is achievable using the entity service. Please see below example:

```js
const posts = await strapi.services["api::post.post"].find({
  filters: {
    thread: entity[0].id,
    parent: { id: { $null: true } }
  },
  fields: ["name"],
});
```